# Open a .txt file that has been declared with a .mo extention

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, modelica

I have a regular text.txt file that is being used in a different program with the file extension .mo

I want to access the text with open(), but for that, I have to change the extension of the file. In the end, the extension should reverse to .mo :

```
path = "dymtest.txt"
file_name = Path(path_dym)
file_name.rename(file_name.with_suffix(".txt"))

with open(file_name) as chat:
   lines = chat.readlines()

file_name.rename(file_name.with_suffix(".txt"))
```

I'd say that opening the file as a .mo to read the text should be possible. Additionally, a solution needs to be able to read and write that file.

Comment: you could just do `open('file.mo')` and it should work

Comment: *" but for that, I have to change the extension of the file"* - No, you don't have to do that. Python does not care one bit about what extension a file has. (In fact, "file extensions" do not exist. It's a human concept to call the letters after the last dot in a filename the "file extension". Computers don't care.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned above, python don't care about file name (including extension). While you *do know* what is the file structure and how to work with it — just do it.

If `.mo` actually contains text — open this file in text mode (which is default), read/process/write it.